# How to get property of the 'record' type using TypInfo unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have this record type

```
TDoublePoint = record
               X : Double;
               Y : Double;
               end;
```

then I have object with this property

```
uses ..TypInfo;

TCell = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FZoom : TDoublePoint 
  published
    property Zoom : TDoublePoint read FZoom write FZoom;
end;
```

But when I want to get **PropInfo** of this property with this function:

```
function GetKind(AObject:TObject; Propertyname :shortstring):TTypeKind;
var p :ppropinfo;
begin
  p:=GetPropInfo(AObject, Propertyname);  // <p = nil
  Result:= p^.proptype^.Kind;
end;
```

..
..

```
c := TCell.Create;
GetKind(c, 'Zoom');  //   <- error
c.Free;
```

I get error, because variable ***p is nil*** in the function.

But Why?
There is `tkRecord` in the TTypeKind, so I expected no problems to read/write the property of record type, but it seems, it is not possible (?)
Google search did not tell much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delphi 7 does not generate RTTI for a record type by default, and so a `published` property that uses a record type will not have RTTI, either (you can use `TypInfo.GetPropList()` to confirm that).

At one point, this was a documented limitation:

> **Published properties are restricted to certain data types**. Ordinal, string, class, interface, variant, and method-pointer types can be published.

However, there is a workaround.  *IF* a record type contains any compiler-managed data types (long strings, interfaces, dynamic arrays, etc), then RTTI will be generated for that record type, as will any `published` property that uses that record type, and thus `GetPropInfo()` can find such properties (I have confirmed that this does work in Delphi 7).

Your `TDoublePoint` record does not contain any compiler-managed data types, so that is why `GetPropInfo()` is returning nil for your `TCell.Zoom` property.

That RTTI issue was fixed in a later version (not sure which one. I'm guessing maybe in Delphi 2010, when Extended RTTI was first introduced).  For instance, the code you have shown works for me as-is in XE.  `GetPropInfo()` can find the `Zoom` property as expected, without having to introduce any compiler-managed types into the `TDoublePoint` record type.

Comment: thanx for clarification... the only way to workaround, is to change record to object, I see

Comment: Yes, and make sure it derives from `TPersistent` or a descendant of it.

Comment: Actually, my answer was a little misleading.  It *IS* possible in Delphi 7, but it is probably not the solution you are hoping for.  I have updated my answer.